# how to solve derivatives with xml?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to write an xml document that can solve derivatives. Unfortunately I don't have all the necessary skills. So far I've made this:

```
<derivador>
  <funcion>Funcion Original: </funcion>  
   <arg>3</arg>
      <variable>x</variable>
      <exponente>^</exponente>
       <numero>2</numero>
  <op>+</op>
   <arg>2</arg>
      <variable>x</variable>
      <exponente>^</exponente>
       <numero>4</numero>

</derivador>
```

And the thing is that I don't understand how is it possible to make mathematical operations here. How do I make it solve the simple derivative of the function f(x) = 3x^2 + 2x^4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand how is it possible to make mathematical operations
>   here.

Try this as your starting point:

**XML**

```
<polynomial>
    <term>
        <coefficient>3</coefficient>
        <variable>x</variable>
        <degree>2</degree>
    </term>
    <term>
        <coefficient>2</coefficient>
        <variable>x</variable>
        <degree>4</degree>
    </term>
</polynomial>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/polynomial">
    <derivative>
        <xsl:for-each select="term">
            <xsl:copy>
                <coefficient>
                    <xsl:value-of select="coefficient * degree" />
                </coefficient>
                <xsl:copy-of select="variable"/>
                <degree>
                    <xsl:value-of select="degree - 1" />
                </degree>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </derivative>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<derivative>
   <term>
      <coefficient>6</coefficient>
      <variable>x</variable>
      <degree>1</degree>
   </term>
   <term>
      <coefficient>8</coefficient>
      <variable>x</variable>
      <degree>3</degree>
   </term>
</derivative>
```

***Note***: this is **not** supposed to be a recipe for solving derivatives, only a demo of how to perform arithmetic operations in XSLT.